# How to combine ListFragment and AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, material-design, android-listfragment, appcompatactivity

This is a very noob question. I am using a ListFragment to show the list of different things in my app. Now I want to apply material design using App Bar (Toolbar) instead of ActionBar to support wide range of devices. In [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html), to use app bar, an activity has to extend AppCompatActivity. But I already extended ListFragment in my code as follows:

```
public class BookListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getActivity(), bookList, 0);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So, how can I extend AppCompatActivity in my BookListFragment?

Comment: ListFragment is a Fragment and there is no need to change it. Do you mean ListActivity?

Comment: As said higher it's fragment and you cannot just change it to AppCompatActivity, but if you use ListActivity from support library (I don't know whether it has this activity) then activity already extends from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: If support library hasn't ListActivity then you can just use AppCompatActivity with ListView or RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You can extend AppCompatActivity without any problems:

Insert a listview into your activitys layout xml file. You already have one (because you used ListActivity), so change its id:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/activity_list"></Listview>
```

now use this ListView in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_list);
    BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getActivity(), bookList, 0);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: thanks but now it shows the error "cannot resolve method findViewById(int)".

Comment: don't forget to add `setContentView()` directly below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, otherwise `findViewById()` has no reference as to where it should find its Views from